# How to replace all the numbers with literal \d in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to write a function, to replace all the numbers in a string with literal `\d`. My code is:

```
val r = """\d""".r
val s = r.replaceAllIn("123abc", """\d""")
println(s)
```

I expect the result is `\d\d\dabc`, but get:

```
dddabc
```

Then I change my code (line 2) to:

```
val s = r.replaceAllIn("123abc", """\\d""")
```

The result is correct now: `\d\d\dabc`

But I don't understand why the method `replaceAllIn` converts the string, not use it directly?

---

There was a `toList` in my previous code, that now what I want. I have just update the question. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: `"Foo".toList` returns a List[Char] and `\d` is not one Char it is two `Char`s `\ ` and `d`. Why you want to do that?

Comment: Sorry, the code is not what I wanted. I'm updating the question now

Comment: By “numbers”, do you mean `\pN` or `\p{Nd}`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `toList`.

```
val r = """\d""".r
val list = r.replaceAllIn("123abc", """\\d""")
println(list)
```

`String`s are (implicitly, via [`WrappedString`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html), convertible to) `Seq[Char]`. If you invoke `toList`, you will have a `List[Char]`.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's `Regex` uses `java.util.regex` underneath (at least on the JVM). Now, if you look up `replaceAll` on Java docs, you'll see this:

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar
>   signs (`$`) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string. Dollar
>   signs may be treated as references to
>   captured subsequences as described
>   above, and backslashes are used to
>   escape literal characters in the
>   replacement string.

Comment: It drives me nuts having to dig through the source and look up JavaDoc to understand how to use this method.  It's even worse for the overload which takes a Match=>String because you need to remember to escape characters in your string! https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5437